# Convert String to an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, object

I i made an array with variables adding strings and variables, and i want to add this string to another array, the problem is that when i console log it with javascript it shows as a string and not as an array, this also makes so i can't acces the array data. This is my code:

```
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        $currentusername = $data['username'];
        $currentpassword = $data['password'];
        $currentage = $data['age'];
        $objectresult = "['Username' => ${currentusername}, 'Password' => ${currentpassword}, 'Age' => ${currentage}]";
        
        print $objectresult."<br/>";
        array_push($usuarios, $objectresult);
    }
    ?>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        var num = <?php echo json_encode($usuarios) ?>;
        for(let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            console.log(num[i]);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You build `$objectresult` as a string - is there any reason that you don't create it as an array?

Comment: PHP's `json_encode()` turns an array into a string. It sounds like you want to use Javascript's `JSON.parse()` function, e.g. `var num = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($usuarios) ?>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the array in quotes, it should be an ordinary PHP array.

```
$objectresult = ['Username' => $currentusername, 'Password' => $currentpassword, 'Age' => $currentage];
```